# How do I use basic grep commands in Unix?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I need to display all the lines using the `grep` command that contain 2-6 'x's

Also need to know how to display all lines with 3 consecutive 'x's

I have tried `grep x{2,6} example.txt` but I keep getting an error saying that `x6` is not found in the directory. My example file contains 7 lines increasing in the amount of 'x's by one in each line.

Comment: You mean two to 6 consecutive `x`'s?

Comment: Keep in mind that something containing 8 x values also matches x{2,6} .

Comment: Yes consecutive sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The Bash shell uses [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) to expand:

```
grep x{2,6} example.txt
```

into:

```
grep x2 x6 example.txt
```

Unless you have a file called `x6` in your directory, you will get an error from `grep` telling you it can't open it.

- Rule 1: enclose regular expressions to `grep` inside quotes — single quotes whenever possible.

Hence, use:

```
grep 'x{2,6}' example.txt
```

This deals with getting a regex to `grep`.  Now we need to consider what it means.  By default, this means look for the characters `x`, `{`, `2`, `,`, `6`, `}` on a single line.  Adding the `-E` option uses extended regular expressions, and the command looks for anything from 2 to 6 consecutive x's on a single line in the file:

```
grep -E 'x{2,6}' example.txt
```

However, it might be worth noting that this is pretty much the same as selecting `'xx'` unless you have colouration on, or are selecting 'only' the matched text (the GNU `grep` extension `-o` option).

These are all for 2-6 adjacent x's, which is roughly what your proposed regex wanted.

You ask about three adjacent x's:

```
grep 'xxx' example.txt
```

The single quotes aren't 100% necessary, but they do no harm and remind you to use them for the regex in general.

Now we face the dilemma that you probably meant "between 2 and 6 x's on a single line, not necessarily adjacent, and not 0 or 1, nor 7 or more".

- Rule 2: describe your required result precisely

Imprecise requirements lead to incorrect, or unintended, results.  Meeting that requirement needs a more complex regex:

```
grep -E '^([^x]*x){2,6}[^x]*$' example.txt
```

That looks for 2-6 occurrences of zero or more non-x's followed by an x at the start of the line, followed by zero or more non-x's up to the end of line.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to display all the lines using GREP command that contain 2-6 'x's

```
grep -P '^(?:[^x]*x[^x]*){2,6}$' file
```

> Also need to know how to display all lines with 3 consecutive 'x's

```
grep -P 'xxx' file
```

Comment: @PSkocik why you delete your answer?

Comment: I realized the 3 'x' weren't consecutive so I did .*x.*x.*x.* to search for 3 'x's with any characters in between

Comment: Note that removing the `?:` would allow the command to be used with `-E`, which is more portable than the GNU extension option `-P` (for [PCRE](http://pcre.org/) — Perl-compatible regular expressions). It is also not especially efficient because you have two `[^x]*` sequences inside the capturing parentheses; you would do better, therefore, with `grep -E '^([^x]*x){2,6}[^x]*$' example.txt`. Since the question asks about Unix (though it is also tagged Linux), a more general answer is better, in principle. To an old-timer like me, the `-P` option is something of a blunderbuss for many searches.